# Break on subtree modification before page finishes loading

Tags: google-chrome

I'm trying to debug a DOM element which gets its node tree modified by javascript by the time page load is complete. Usually to debug I would hover on element and select break on subtree modifications in Chrome, however in this case that wouldn't work since the tree is modified after page load is complete. Please advise.

Comment: In some cases, such a breakpoint remains even after reloading the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `debugger` keyword in the Javascript code where you want the execution to pause:

```
function addNode() {
    debugger
    ...
}
```

Alternately, and if it's not your own code, you can [add a breakpoint](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints#loc) in the Javascript file using the Chrome DevTools debugger.